# Incorrect tile repeating in WMS?

Tags: geoserver, wms, google-maps-api

I am trying to leverage my GeoServer and add a WMS layer to a map created with of Google Maps.

What I am getting instead is the tile repeated across the display. I am passing the BBox from the current map extent to the WMS request which works properly as a standalone URL but somehow displays incorrectly on the map.

I am familiar with GeoServer and the WMS request but new to Google Maps JavaScript API.

Here is what I have tried and the resulting image.

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function () {
        var censusLayer =
            new google.maps.ImageMapType(
                {

                    getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
                        var ne = map.getBounds().getNorthEast();
                        var sw = map.getBounds().getSouthWest();
                        var bbox = sw.lng() + "," + sw.lat() + "," + ne.lng() + "," + ne.lat();

                        var container = document.getElementById('map');
                        // from geoserver
                        //http://104.215.74.199:8080/geoserver/hcad/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=hcad:parcels_simple_4326&styles=&bbox=-95.96082688782865,29.497301702948995,-94.90761061770445,30.170549317160965&width=1538&height=517&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng                                
                        // from application
                        //http://104.215.74.199:8080/geoserver/hcad/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=hcad:parcels_simple_4326&styles=&bbox=-97.44697158203127,29.149074739047958,-93.22272841796877,30.381673782887290&width=1538&height517&srs=EPSG:4326&format=image%2Fpng                                

                        //base WMS URL
                        var url = "http://104.215.74.199:8080/geoserver/hcad/wms?"

                        url += "service=WMS";           //WMS service
                        url += "&version=1.1.0";         //WMS version
                        url += "&request=GetMap";        //WMS operation
                        url += "&layers=hcad:parcels_simple_4326"; //WMS layers to draw
                        url += "&styles=";               //use default style
                        url += "&bbox=" + bbox;          //set bounding box for tile
                        url += "&width=256" //+ container.offsetWidth;
                        url += "&height=256" //+ container.offsetHeight;
                        url += "&srs=EPSG:4326";         //projection WGS84;
                        url += "&format=image%2Fpng";      //image format
                        url += "&TRANSPARENT=TRUE";      //only draw areas where we have data
                        url += "&tiled=true";

                        console.log(url);
                        return url; //return WMS URL for the tile
                        return container;
                    },

                    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                    opacity: 0.5,
                    isPng: true
                });

        //add WMS layer to map
        map.overlayMapTypes.push(censusLayer);
    });
}
```

And the result so far...

[image]

Comment: Google maps uses EPSG:3857 not EPSG:4326

Comment: Thanks for sharing @IanTurton. for simplicity I have reuploaded to geoserver in crs 3857 and adjusted the srs parameter to match.  Now I recieve no error and no image? Is there anything missing from the request?